# Scraping deliveroo price

Tags: python, web-scraping

I should do some web scraping of multiple deliveroo sites, the information I need to extract is the header of the various products and the price.
I have tried using the BeautifulSoup library, but the information I need to extract is quite nested.
I set up the code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
#the website URL
url_link = "https://deliveroo.it/en/menu/jesolo/jesolo/burger-king-jesolo"
result = requests.get(url_link)
print(result)
```

I can tell from here that I can do scraping because the result is: <Response [200]>

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(result, "html.parser")
print(doc.prettify())
```

[Deliveroo html site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97y9A.png)

The end result should be a database with title and price information, for example:

- Plant based nuggets burger - menu -> 8.20
- Crazy cheese bbq - menu -> 11.10
- etc.

From here I can't go any further, I hope I was clear with respect to what I need to do, in case anyone can solve the problem I would be very grateful

EDIT 1

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

siti=["https://deliveroo.it/it/menu/roma/piazza-venezia/burger-king-via
nazionale","https://deliveroo.it/en/menu/jesolo/jesolo/burger-king
jesolo",'https://deliveroo.it/it/menu/roma/via-tiburtina/burger-king
via-tiburtina']

for url in siti:
  result = requests.get(url)
  doc = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")
  menus = doc.findAll("div", class_="UIMenuItemCard-3b733b66e7f3b27d")
  db_name=[]
  db_price=[]
  for menu in menus:
    name = menu.find("p", class_="ccl-a396bc55704a9c8a")
    price = menu.find("span", class_="ccl-08c109442f3e666d")
    #print(name.text + " > " + price.text)

    db_name.append(name.text)
    db_price.append(price.text)

df_name = pd.DataFrame (db_name, columns = ['name'])
df_price = pd.DataFrame (db_price, columns = ['price'])
df=df_name.join(df_price)
```

I went ahead with the work and now I can't scrap multiple sites, the moment I launch this code it scrapes the last URL in the list. I should be scraping all the different sites at the same time and putting them into a dataframe. So in output I would need a table always with two columns (name and price) of all URLs together, if possible every time it changes URL insert a space. If anyone could help me I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

First what you have to do is find the **parent element** (wrapped element) and then **iterate** over it looking for the elements you want.
You need to do something like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_link = "https://deliveroo.it/en/menu/jesolo/jesolo/burger-king-jesolo"
result = requests.get(url_link)
doc = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")

menus = doc.findAll("div", class_="UIMenuItemCard-3b733b66e7f3b27d")
for menu in menus:
    name = menu.find("p", class_="ccl-a396bc55704a9c8a")
    price = menu.find("span", class_="ccl-08c109442f3e666d")
    print(name.text + " > " + price.text)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Plant based nuggets burger - menù > €8.20
Crazy cheese bbq - menù > €11.10
Crazy cheese chicken bbq - menù > €11.10
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply @MeT, as the first step the result I wanted to achieve was just that!
The second step would be to do scraping with as many Urls that I have in a list.  
[https://deliveroo.it/it/menu/roma/piazza-venezia/burger-king-via-nazionale, https://deliveroo.it/it/menu/roma/torrino-fonte-ostiense/burger-king-eur,
https://deliveroo.it/en/menu/jesolo/jesolo/burger-king-jesolo, etc.]

As a final output I would need a pandas db with the two columns name and price, containing all the data divided by each store. 
Thank you in advance if you answer me again.